# Deploying App With Dummy/Initial Data

Tags: iphone, core-data

I have a Core Data based application that stores hierarchal data displayed using a series of UITableViews.  To illustrate my app functionality to the user I would like to pre-populate my database/app with some dummy values.  This data would be available upon installation on the user's iPhone/iPod Touch.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the data and include it in the app bundle. On first launch, copy that sqlite file to the documents directory and then stand up the core data stack afterwards.

Personally i would create a desktop app using the same model to do the initial data entry to make it easier on you.  From there take the sqlite file that is generated and include it in your appilcation.